# Resetting bluetooth on Archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, bluetooth

Sometimes it happens that my bluetooth mouse gets disconnected from my laptop.
Switching off/on the mouse doesn't help. Switching off/on my laptop bluetooth doesn't help either.
Not even `systemctl restart bluetooth.service` helps.

But if I close my laptop lid to put in sleep and reopen it after a few seconds the connection with the bt mouse is re-established and all works fine then.

Also a reboot doesn't help. I have to power off / on the laptop

**EDIT:**
As requested, here is some debug info:

```
$ systemctl status bluetooth.service

● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-09-05 09:44:14 CEST; 4h 5min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 388 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 3.4M
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─388 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

set 05 09:44:17 xps-13-luca bluetoothd[388]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
set 05 09:44:17 xps-13-luca bluetoothd[388]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
set 05 09:49:50 xps-13-luca bluetoothd[388]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.159 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
set 05 09:49:50 xps-13-luca bluetoothd[388]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.159 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
set 05 09:49:50 xps-13-luca bluetoothd[388]: RFCOMM server failed for Headset Voice gateway: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
set 05 09:49:50 xps-13-luca bluetoothd[388]: RFCOMM server failed for :1.159/Profile/HSPHSProfile/00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (9>
set 05 13:48:06 xps-13-luca bluetoothd[388]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
set 05 13:48:06 xps-13-luca bluetoothd[388]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
set 05 13:48:06 xps-13-luca bluetoothd[388]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.159 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
set 05 13:48:06 xps-13-luca bluetoothd[388]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.159 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```

Please consider that the `Address already in use` occurred several hours before the bt mouse issue

Output of `journalctl -xe` is quite long....
https://pastebin.com/gViN5Tqp

Comment: Have you find the culprit? Do you have USB 3.0 devices plugged to your laptop when this happens?

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest thing is to use `bluetoothctl` to simply switch the bluetooth controller itself on and off.

`echo -e 'show\npower off\npower on\nquit' | bluetoothctl`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
`sudo rfkill block bluetooth && sleep 0.1 && sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth;`

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please consider editing your post to include some information on _how_ this command sequence solves the OPs problem, and how you concluded from the OPs description what the cause of the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Try to unload/load (`modprobe`) Bluetooth modules.

Comment: well, this worked for me. all wireless communications were unblocked by rfkill, even restarting bluetooth service didn't fix it. but unloading and loading **btusb** module did the magic, I'm not sure what was the problem, couldn't see any error in journal. but definitely the trick was to reload its module. still can't confirm this is a permanent fix.